# How to extract/fix double quoted data within a json-like text

Tags: node.js, json

I have very large json-like text object which have content like the following

```
{"key":" "somevalue" ", "key2": " "value2" ",  "key3":" value3 "} should output "somevalue" and "value2"
```

using `JSON.parse` directly throws errors due to unescaped characters, I've tried several regex to find and replace those double quoted values without succuess, is there an easy way to solve that ?